# Specified Android native API level 'android-8' is not supported by your NDK/toolchain

Tags: android, opencv, javacv

Specified Android native API level 'android-8' is not supported by your
  NDK/toolchain. 
I am getting this error while trying to build JavaCV for android. It says [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6493) in comments that specifying native api level using -D options will resolve the issue. The command I have used is :

mvn clean install -Djavacpp.platform=android-arm -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=android-16-Djavacpp.platform.root=/Users/user/android-sdk-macosx/ndk-bundle -Djavacpp.platform.compiler=

What am a I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

-DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=16

look into ndk-src/platforms that you have the api-level you choose.